# Ошибка "C:\Python27\Scripts\python" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: python, python-2.x, pip

Мои данные:
Python27
Windows XP
Windows 7 Starter
C:\Python27

Пытаюсь установить модуль BeautifulSoup в cmd

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Получаю ответ:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что в `C:\Python27\Scripts` у вас находиться сам `pip.exe`, посмотрите на файлы в папке. Оттуда можно установить вот так: `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install bs4`
Или из папки `C:\Python27` вот так: `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install bs4`

Answer (score 0):

Напишите только

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```